# Mysql create table query problems?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to create a table, which name something like :

name_thisyear_thisweekofyear, e.g -> name_2009_40

I tried this query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name_YEAR(NOW())_WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, phone_no int, created datetime, deleted datetime)

It doesnt work. Please help

Error Message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOW())_WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, userid int,' at line 1

Comment: it might help if you posted up any error messages you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can't work, because parantheses are not allowed in table names (unless you escape them properly using backticks)

mysql sees your query as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
name_YEAR(
    NOW()      # this is causing an error already
)
/*GARBAGE: */_WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, phone_no int, created datetime, deleted datetime)
```

i don't know if it's possible at all, to create parts of table names dynamically and concatenating the parts together in the end.

the easy way would be to calculate the name in php and create the query out of php

Comment: I tried backslash, cant work. How to make it works? tbale name "name_year_week"?

Comment: create the table name in another language!

Comment: @knittl: is this the only way??

Comment: as far as i know: yes, and all the others share the same opinion …

sql wasn't designed to allow such things

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that... You must specify table name, a function can't be executed there

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it. The set of alphanumeric characters from the current character set, “_”, and “$” are not special.

Comment: so, how to create a table with that name format? name_'year'_'week'??

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Table and column names must be given as an [indentifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html).

PS: To concatenate elsewhere, use concat().

Comment: not quite correct, tables names must—if necessary—quoted by backticks (\`), not by quotation marks (") like strings. but yes, they must be fixed text